# Why would I want to use CRaSH?

Tags: java, shell

Justed stumbled across [CRaSH](http://julienviet.com/crash/) and although it looks mighty interesting, I'm wondering why a Java developer should invest time & energy into learning (yet another) shell language. What sort of standard- and cool-applications can CRaSH be used for? Is this like a Groovy-version of Jython?

I guess, when the dust settles, I'm looking for CRaSH's "wow" factors. I'm sure they're there, but after spending ~20 minutes perusing the documentation I'm just not seeing them. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is just another implementation of a very old trick. I've been embedding debugging/prototyping shells into my applications ever since Fortran. Any scripting language with a REPL would be sufficient (I actually used Jython this way, as well as Iron Python for .NET).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Possible Uses

#### Fast Prototyping

You could do this with Groovy or others, so that's not a very strong point, but as CRaSH gives you code-level access to the JVM and the processes it runs, it may come in handy to just keep a JVM running and experiment with small code snippets (for instance, using it as a REPL to implement solutions to StackOverflow questions).

The [JCR extension](http://julienviet.com/crash/#d5e237) would seem potentially useful to supplement this, by giving you shell access to remote repositories, and contains a notion of [workspace](http://julienviet.com/crash/#d5e257) to separate projects.

#### Interacting with a Running Process

I could see this being an interesting use case. I don't know of many good process inspection command-line tools for JVM processes, apart from the JDK-packaged ones. CRaSH might help in interacting with them in novel ways.

For instance, you can use the [Attach Mode](http://julienviet.com/crash/#d5e74) to attach to a running JVM, and then use the [`thread`](http://julienviet.com/crash/#d5e209) command to `ls`, `dump` or `interrupt` threads.

You could also write some [additional control commands](http://julienviet.com/crash/#d5e487) for non-programmers to use CRaSH to perform routine maintenance and monitoring.

#### Content Repository Management

The [JCR extension](http://julienviet.com/crash/#d5e237) seems to be very interesting as well, as it would give a Java-scriptable access to remote development environments.   It could also simply allow content-editors to access and edit remote content, when used in the context of CMS-type apps built on top of a [JCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_repository_API_for_Java)-capable [content repository](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_repository).

#### What Others Say About CRaSH

- An [introductory blog post by the CRaSH author, about its use at eXoPlatform](http://www.exoplatform.com/company/en/resource-viewer/Tutorial/Introduction-to-Crash). And the fact that it is officially supported by [eXoPlatform](http://www.exoplatform.com) is an indicator that's it potentially good stuff :)
- Not much to read, but of interest: French technologist [Didier Girard](https://plus.google.com/115263933340916245640) [re-posted it](https://plus.google.com/115263933340916245640/posts/HEgKMUcrH9C).

---

### Summary

Basically, I see it as a **power-user** or **administrator** interface to JVM processes, built on top of Groovy and networking protocols. So it combines the power of scripting with a nice facade and some built-in connectors.

---

### Note on Flexibility

I agree with SK-logic: most of this can be done with most JVM-languages, and they provide more and flexibility. But CRaSH might provide a shorter path to achieving such goals.

The same applies to the JCR extension capabilities: you can achieve this by glueing together a few age-old and time-tested tools. But this might be a shorter and simpler path (like commands for the heroku platform, or PaaS services, for instance).

Comment: You can use any scripting language with a REPL for debugging a running process. Of course you have to plug your own telnet/ssh listener there.

Comment: @SK-logic: you can, but you would need to code in some of the actions. Whereas here it seems like CRaSH attempts to already give you some control, treating the JVM as a system (which it is) to allow you to nagivate it and query and update its properties. To me that seems potentially interesting. I haven't tried it yet, but probably will soon-ish.

Comment: in Jython you can instantiate any JVM class, call any method, etc. - just same as in this shell. It is interesting, yes, but not unique.

Comment: @SK-logic: nobody said it was unique either. And I know you can instantiate objects with Jython (or JRuby, or Groovy, or Clojure, or Scala, ...), but the point is that it's a **programming activity**. It's totally different than from giving a user interface to people that **may not** be programmers, or who may not want to have to type in code, but just simpler, more familiar commands. I think you see this too much from the eye of a developer.

Comment: @haylem - thanks (+1)! However, your answer is just a little too vague for me to give it the final green check. Can you please clarify a few things: (1) what do you mean (specifically) by "fast prototyping"? And (2) What JVM properties can you modify while it is running? Can you list 2 or 3 specific use cases here - where a CRSH scripter would do such a thing, and why? I'm just having a problem "seeing the forest through the trees." Thanks again!

Comment: @AdamTannon: I'm glad if it helps. I expanded a bit. I honestly haven't played with it yet, and won't for a bit, but I just think it could be interesting. For all we know, that's just someone's pet project, but it looks like there's a potential for some niche users.